# Animated background causing scrolling issues

Tags: html, css

I've built a website using this animation as a background, with clouds removed:
https://codepen.io/WebSonick/pen/vjmgu

The excess content on the website requires scrolling in order for it to be readable as a whole.

The animated background prevents the website from scrolling, leaving it in a bugged state with a white bar on the bottom. **Here's a video showing this issue:**
https://youtu.be/UBK4j5or6KU

Here's my code:

**HTML:**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <title></title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="content">
        <img src="test1.png" width="450">
        <p><a href="index2.html">episode 1</a></p>
        <p><a href="index3.html">episode 2</a></p>
        <p><a href="index4.html">episode 3</a></p>
        <p><a href="index5.html">episode 4</a></p>
        <p><a href="index6.html">episode 5</a></p>
        <p><a href="index7.html">episode 6</a></p>
        <p><a href="index8.html">episode 7</a></p>
        <p><a href="index9.html">episode 8</a></p>
        <p><a href="index10.html">episode 9</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="stars"></div>
    <div class="twinkling"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**CSS:**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: tt2020;
  src: url(TT2020StyleB-Regular.woff2);
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 2;
}

.content a {
  color:#ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.content p {
   font-family: tt2020;
    font-size: 35px;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align:center;
}

@keyframes move-twink-back {
    from {background-position:0 0;}
    to {background-position:-10000px 5000px;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes move-twink-back {
    from {background-position:0 0;}
    to {background-position:-10000px 5000px;}
}
@-moz-keyframes move-twink-back {
    from {background-position:0 0;}
    to {background-position:-10000px 5000px;}
}
@-ms-keyframes move-twink-back {
    from {background-position:0 0;}
    to {background-position:-10000px 5000px;}
}

.stars, .twinkling {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display:block;

}

.stars {
  background:#000 url(http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/360/images/stars.png) repeat top center;
  z-index:0;
}

.twinkling{
  background:transparent url(http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/360/images/twinkling.png) repeat top center;
  z-index:0;

  -moz-animation:move-twink-back 200s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation:move-twink-back 200s linear infinite;
  -o-animation:move-twink-back 200s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation:move-twink-back 200s linear infinite;
  animation:move-twink-back 200s linear infinite;
}
```

If I remove the animated background, the issue solves itself. **Hence my question: is it possible to solve this issue without giving up on the background?**
If not, how could I find an alternative for such a background?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it by using `position: fixed` instead of `position: absolute` on the `stars` and `twinkling` elements.
This is the result:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: tt2020;
  src: url(TT2020StyleB-Regular.woff2);
}


.content {
   position: relative;
   text-align: center;
   z-index: 1;
}

.content a {
  color:#ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.content p {
   font-family: tt2020;
    font-size: 35px;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align:center;
}

@keyframes move-twink-back {
    from {background-position:0 0;}
    to {background-position:-10000px 5000px;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes move-twink-back {
    from {background-position:0 0;}
    to {background-position:-10000px 5000px;}
}
@-moz-keyframes move-twink-back {
    from {background-position:0 0;}
    to {background-position:-10000px 5000px;}
}
@-ms-keyframes move-twink-back {
    from {background-position:0 0;}
    to {background-position:-10000px 5000px;}
}

.stars, .twinkling {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display:block;

}

.stars {
  background:#000 url(http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/360/images/stars.png) repeat top center;
  z-index:0;
}

.twinkling{
  background:transparent url(http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/360/images/twinkling.png) repeat top center;
  z-index:0;

  -moz-animation:move-twink-back 200s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation:move-twink-back 200s linear infinite;
  -o-animation:move-twink-back 200s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation:move-twink-back 200s linear infinite;
  animation:move-twink-back 200s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
        <img src="test1.png" width="450">
        <p><a href="index2.html">episode 1</a></p>
        <p><a href="index3.html">episode 2</a></p>
        <p><a href="index4.html">episode 3</a></p>
        <p><a href="index5.html">episode 4</a></p>
        <p><a href="index6.html">episode 5</a></p>
        <p><a href="index7.html">episode 6</a></p>
        <p><a href="index8.html">episode 7</a></p>
        <p><a href="index9.html">episode 8</a></p>
        <p><a href="index10.html">episode 9</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="stars"></div>
    <div class="twinkling"></div>
```

Comment: Worked beautifully. Thank you very much!

Comment: @user14861400 You're welcome :) Please mark the answer as accepted if it solved the issue.